# Is there any way to use calabash-android without gem install command

Tags: calabash

Is there any way to use calabash-android without gem install command?

I do not want to use gem install command and wants just folder where it is extracted. Is is it possible to do it?

I am using windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone Git repository and build that using rake build command. Also you can refer [calabash-android build](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/Building-calabash-android) which explains all the steps.